# How can I protect pine from yellowing?

Tags: wood, sealing, staining, wooden-furniture, wood-finishing

I have read that pine can begin to yellow very quickly.  I am wanting to use pine as an office desk top and want to prevent this yellowing from occurring.

- Would a oil- or water-based sealant be the answer here?
- Would a stain help in "masking" the yellowing effect?
- What kind of protection is best? I don't know much except that there are different types: polyurethane, shellac and varnish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wood will change color eventually no matter what you do. However, you can do two things to slow down that process.

1. Use a water-based polyurethane finish. All other finishes are either slightly yellow going on, or themselves yellow with age.
2. Keep the sun off the wood. Sunlight hastens the darkening process.
3. A dark stain will mask the effect. The darker the better.